# How I can bind and access properties from both $root and current collection?

Tags: knockout.js

In my case I have one view model which contains:

- collection of usernames with id/name object
- collection of tasks of which one attribute (assigned task) points to username id

I would like to display list of tasks and for each task display dropdown available usernames and mark one which is currently selected. So view model looks like e.g.:

```
var viewmodel = {
     usernames: ko.observableArray([ { id: 1, name: "Foo" }, { id: 2, name: "Bar" } ]),
     tasks: ko.observableArray([ { project_id: 1, name: "First", assignee: 1 } ])
}
```

Now I would like to do something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="projects">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="name" />
        <select data-bind="$root.usernames">
             <option data-bind="attr: { value: id }, text: name" />
        </select>
   </li>
</ul>
```

My question is how to write data-bind statement for `<option>` element so it will create `selected` attribute which will be true only in case that `username.id` is the same as `task.assignee`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use them interchangeably -

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.usernames, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: $parent.selectedUser">
</select>
```

You don't need to specify the options explicitly like that, use the optionsText and optionsValue bindings, and use the value binding to show what you want to select.